# Find the leftmost duplicate in bisect search

Tags: python

I read [Binary search algorithm - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to bisect search the leftmost element of duplicates
The psudocodes:

```
function binary_search_leftmost(A, n, T):
    L := 0
    R := n
    while L < R:
        m := floor((L + R) / 2)
        if A[m] < T:
            L := m + 1
        else:
            R := m
    return L
```

Implement in python

```
def search_leftmost(nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    if len(nums) < 1: return [-1, -1]
    lo = 0
    hi = len(nums)
    logging.debug(f"nums:{list(enumerate(nums))}, target: {target}")
    while lo < hi: 
        mid = (lo+hi) // 2
        logging.debug(f"lo:{lo} mid:{mid} hi:{hi}")
        if target > nums[lo]:
            lo = mid + 1
        else:
            hi = mid 
    logging.debug(f"lo: {lo}")
    return lo
```

Unfortunately, when test with `nums = [5,7,7,8,8,8,8,10]; target = 8`

```
$ python 0.bi_search.py 
DEBUG nums:[(0, 5), (1, 7), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 8), (5, 8), (6, 8), (7, 10)], target: 8
DEBUG lo:0 mid:4 hi:8
DEBUG lo:5 mid:6 hi:8
DEBUG lo:5 mid:5 hi:6
DEBUG lo: 5
```

It return 5 which is neither leftmost or rightmost.

What's the problem with my implementation?

Comment: Is the expected output for `nums = [5,7,7,8,8,8,8,10]; target = 8` is 3?

Comment: yes, I want to get the leftmost element. @arsho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in implementation.

Pseudocode

```
if A[m] < T:
  L := m + 1
```

Was implemented as

```
if target > nums[lo]: # this should be if nums[mid] < target:
    lo = mid + 1
```

I have updated it and it is working as expected:

```
def search_leftmost(nums, target):
    lo = 0
    hi = len(nums)
    while lo < hi: 
        mid = (lo+hi) // 2
        if nums[mid] < target:
            lo = mid + 1
        else:
            hi = mid
    return lo

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nums = [5,7,7,8,8,8,8,10]
    target = 8    
    assert search_leftmost(nums, target)== 3


    nums = [5,7,7,8,8,8,8,10]
    target = 7
    assert search_leftmost(nums, target) == 1


    nums = [5,7,7,8,8,8,8,10]
    target = 10
    assert search_leftmost(nums, target) == 7

    print("Done")
```

According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm):

> Even if T is not in the array, L
>   is the rank of T in the array, or the number of
>   elements in the array that are less than T.